# VBS: Word.Documents.Open fails unattended

Tags: ms-word, vbscript, ms-office, windows-server-2012

I have a VBS script that loops over doc and docx Word files and converts them to PDF. I run the script from a Windows 2021 server machine. I know that Microsoft discourages server-side automation for office, but in my environment I have no choice.

The script runs fine interactively. However, once ran via task scheduler when I'm logged out, the script fails because method Documents.Open fails:

```
'file is a handle to a file on the filesystem
Set doc = oWord.Documents.Open(CStr(file), , , msoFalse) 'This fails
```

The script simply stops, the task scheduler returns code 0 for the task.
Creating the following folders didn't help:

```
 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
 C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
```

How can I diagnose the issue?

Comment: Hence, why Microsoft doesn't support server-side automation of Office.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VB Script Documents.Open throwing 424 error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2105534)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid it does not. I created the folders, the script still fails.